# What is the type of of Mui Datepicker params?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

The [mui Datepicker](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/desktop-date-picker/) wraps a Textfield and passes params to it. Typescript needs to to know the type of params, how can I fix the type of params?

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2jit5u?file=/demo.tsx)

```
<DatePicker
label="Basic example"
value={value}
onChange={(newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
}}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

Comment: It says ```MuiTextFieldPropsType``` [here](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/desktop-date-picker/#props), near ```renderInput``` field.

Comment: @Oleksii I don't know from where to import MuiTextFieldPropsType

Comment: Well, actually, ts should pickup this type by default, as this prop is specified to have params of this type, but anyway, ```MuiTextFieldPropsType``` appears to be just a type alias for ```TextFieldProps``` that you can import from ```{ TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField'```

Comment: @Oleksii you are right thank you! import TextField, { TextFieldProps as MuiTextFieldPropsType } from "@mui/material/TextField"